# Why won't Antenna House Formatter 6.2 on Windows 10 x64 recognize my Helvetica fonts?

Tags: fonts, xsl-fo, antenna-house

On Windows 10, whether using the Antenna House 6.2 GUI or via command line through oXygen 23, Antenna House is not acknowledging my Helvetica fonts.

*(confirmation that they are installed)*

[image]

*(Antenna House font-config.xml)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- DOCTYPE font-config SYSTEM "font-config.dtd" -->
<font-config
    otf-metrics-mode="typographic"
    name-processing-mode="windows-name">
  <!-- add your font folder here -->
  <font-folder path="C:\Windows\Fonts"/>
</font-config>
```

(reference within XSL)

```
<fo:block font-family="Helvetica" ...
```

(error from Antenna House as shown within oXygen 23)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual advice for Windows is to not use a `font-config.xml` file because AH Formatter on Windows searches `C:\Windows\Fonts` by default.  See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/v70e/ahf-font.html#font-configration-file

Windows 10 also has per-user font directories. Are you sure that your font did not end up in your per-user directory? AH Formatter V6.2 predates both Windows 10 and the support for per-user directories in later AH Formatter versions. In this case you would need to have your own `font-config.xml` file to get AH Formatter to also search the per-user directory.

If you preview the font on Windows, is the 'Font name:' field just 'Helvetica' or is it something like 'HelveticaRegular'? You should base the `font-family` value on the name in the file.

I am assuming that you are using the `font-config.xml` file in the default location or you are using the correct environment variable to tell AH Formatter where to find another `font-config.xml` file, but you might want to check to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Tony.  The fonts are in "C:\Windows\Fonts," not tied to any particular user.  Font name is confirmed as "Helvetica" during preview.  I was using the "font-config.xml" in the default location, but renamed it just now with a ".bak" extension, to take it out of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, but you've discounted all of my possible answers. All that I have left it to suggest that you restore `C:\Program Files\Antenna House\AHFormatterV66\font-config.xml` to its original contents and set the `AHF62_64_FONT_CONFIGFILE` environment variable to point to it. If you contact Antenna House Support, they may be able to help you more.

Comment: Figured it out!  I got rid of all Helvetica fonts from "C:\Windows\Fonts," reinstalled just the Helvetica Family pack that I had, then set: <font-alias file="HelveticaLTPro-Roman.otf">
            <alias family-name="Helvetica"/>
        </font-alias>
I had other Helvetica files for which I shouldn't have had to do this, but their origin was suspect.  The Helvetica Family pack I mentioned above I purchased personally.  So I believe the dodgy files were not getting installed properly by Windows.

Comment: It's good that you worked this out. I have seen Support issues where the cause turned out to be an improperly installed font, but I hadn't mentioned it because it happens so rarely.